# Como hago para que al momento de imprimir algo, este se repita hasta llenar los mayores espacios posibles de la hoja de impresion

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Aquí está mi código React. Lo que hace es que cuando el usuario presione el botón de imprimir, se muestre la etiqueta una sola vez. Sin embargo, me gustaría que se repita múltiples veces, por ejemplo, 10 veces, y que estas se distribuyan automáticamente alrededor de la página de impresión. No estoy seguro de cómo lograr que, al presionar el botón de imprimir, se genere la etiqueta repetida y se distribuya automáticamente para que aparezcan más de una en la página de impresión. ¿Puedes proporcionarme orientación o un ejemplo de cómo lograr esto? ¡Gracias!

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './LabelDesigner.css';

const LabelDesigner = () => {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState([]);
  const [isPrinting, setIsPrinting] = useState(false);

  const addField = (type) => {
    const newField = {
      id: Date.now(),
      type: type,
      top: 50,
      left: 50,
    };

    setFields([...fields, newField]);
  };

  const handleFieldMouseDown = (e, id) => {
    const handleFieldMouseMove = (e) => {
        const containerRect = document.querySelector('.label-container').getBoundingClientRect();
        const fieldRect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        
        const left = Math.min(Math.max(e.clientX - containerRect.left, 0), containerRect.width - fieldRect.width);
        const top = Math.min(Math.max(e.clientY - containerRect.top, 0), containerRect.height - fieldRect.height);
        
        setFields((prevFields) =>
          prevFields.map((field) => {
            if (field.id === id) {
              return { ...field, left, top };
            }
            return field;
          })
        );
    };

    const handleFieldMouseUp = () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleFieldMouseMove);
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', handleFieldMouseUp);
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleFieldMouseMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', handleFieldMouseUp);
  };
  const handlePrintLabel = () => {
    setIsPrinting(true);
    const labelContainer = document.querySelector('.label-container');
    labelContainer.classList.add('print-label-container');
    window.print();
    labelContainer.classList.remove('print-label-container');
    setIsPrinting(false);    
  };
  

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="label-container">
        {fields.map((field) => (
          <div
            key={field.id}
            className={`field field-${field.type}`}
            style={{ top: field.top, left: field.left }}
            onMouseDown={(e) => handleFieldMouseDown(e, field.id)}
          >
            {field.type}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="fields-container">
        <button onClick={() => addField('barcode')}>Agregar Código de Barras</button>
        <button onClick={() => addField('text')}>Agregar Texto</button>
        <button onClick={() => addField('image')}>Agregar Imagen</button>
        <button onClick={() => addField('date')}>Agregar Fecha</button>
      </div>
      <div className="print-container">
        <button onClick={handlePrintLabel}>
          {isPrinting ? 'Imprimiendo...' : 'Imprimir'}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LabelDesigner;
```

mi css por si hay que modificar algo

```
 .label-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  
  .field {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;
    cursor: move;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  .field-barcode {
    background-color: #eee;
  }
  
  .field-text {
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  
  .field-image {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
  }
  
  .field-date {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
  }
  
  .fields-container {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  @media print {
    body * {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .print-label-container,
    .print-label-container * {
      visibility: visible;
    }
    .print-label-container {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 300px;
      height: 100px;
    }
  }
```